# GSconnect doesn't function on Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine

Tags: connection, phone

I'm trying to install GSconnect on my Ubuntu 18.04 on a virtual machine. I installed it from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/ but it doens't work or it cannot find my device. When I open the KDEconnect app from phone it cannot find my pc.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a firewall issue on the host machine, what have you tried to get it to work?

Comment: At the end, to make it working I had to create a second network adapter from the virtual machine tool. Since the previous one was seen by Ubuntu like a cable connection and not a wireless one.